# How to configure the StatusBarOverlaysWebView phonegap plugin to prevent the status bar from overlapping the app content

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ios7-statusbar

I cannot get it to work. I have added the plugin to the directory via the phonegap CLI, and inserted:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
```

into config.xml in the ios platform block, but the status bar still overlays the content.

Answer (score 2):

Install latest version of cordova statusbar plugin using the following command,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Add following lines in config.xml under ios platform section,

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
```

Remove iOS platform, re-add and build the iOS platform again.